# How to pass Magento Add to Cart Api Custom options in Android?

Tags: android, magento, soap, ksoap2

I am building android application using SOAP API in Magento which has ability to sell products on mobile. I am using KSOAP2 library file.
But problem is that i am not able to add product to cart using function `shoppingCartProductAdd`. Its gives error Product’s data is not valid
So please help me if you have better methode to add a product to cart

Comment: That is the only method through which you can add products to the cart , Before you add product details to the cart , check whether product id/SKU/Name of the product is existed or what

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the session Id , and I hope you have the session ID
and create a shopping cart ID first, Below is the code

```
         //Creation of CART ID
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(MAGENTO_NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartCreate");
        request.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
        env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
        Object result = env.getResponse();
        result = env.getResponse();
        Log.d("cartId", result.toString());
```

Below is the code to add products to the shoppig cart

```
            SoapObject addprod = new SoapObject(MAGENTO_NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductEntity");
            addprod.addProperty("product_id", 1059);
            addprod.addProperty("sku", "ssbadracyonmat035");
            addprod.addProperty("qty", 12);
            SoapObject arrayOfProducts = new SoapObject(MAGENTO_NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductEntityArray");
            arrayOfProducts.addProperty("products", addprod);

            SoapObject cartProductAdd = new SoapObject(MAGENTO_NAMESPACE, "shoppingCartProductAdd ");
            cartProductAdd.addProperty("sessionId", sessionId);
            cartProductAdd.addProperty("quoteId", quoteId);
            cartProductAdd.addProperty("products", arrayOfProducts);
            cartProductAdd.addProperty("storeId", "4");
            env.setOutputSoapObject(cartProductAdd);
            androidHttpTransport.call("", env);
            Log.e("BeforeCall", cartProductAdd.toString());
            Object ResultForProductAddToCart = env.getResponse();
            Log.d("productAddedToCart?", ResultForProductAddToCart.toString());
```